# Storm HDFS locking file from NiFi

Tags: hdfs, apache-storm, apache-nifi

am trying to use storm HDFS spout, I have Apache Nifi moving files to HDFS directory where storm is listening, but as soon as apache nifi starts to move the file, storm senses that and starts processing noting that the file haven't been completely moved.

I have tried to use `conf.put(Configs.IGNORE_SUFFIX, ignoreSuffix)` from storm side
and apache nifi `updateAttribute` to rename the file to `.ignore`
I need to rename the file again after being completely moved, how can I achieve that ? or is there another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing to HDFS, NiFi will write the file with the filename containing a dot at the beginning like ".foo.txt" and when the write operation is complete it will rename it to the name without the dot like "foo.txt". So if Storm has a way to ignore a prefix then you should be able to ignore anything starting with a dot.

Comment: storm has a suffix ignore, can I change that from NIFI side ?

Comment: No that is part of the processor's code in NiFi and can't be changed, if Storm can't do a prefix ignore then you'll probably want to take a different approach where you write to dir1 and storm is watching dir2, and then after PutHDFS you use a MoveHDFS to move from dir1 to dir2

Comment: it seems in linux  adding "." before file name makes it hidden, when I tried again it worked okey